# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I've this code that insert data into database, but I keep getting this error even though I've checked the syntax many times, can anyone help me?
The error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cou ?','output','input','new line', 'break','output','Multiable_Choise')' at line 4

```
<?php
$connectdb = mysql_connect('localhost','root','sara', true ) or die ("Not Connect");
 if (!$connectdb)
{
  die('Could not connect :'. mysql_errno());
 }
 $selestdb  = mysql_select_db('iexa', $connectdb) or die ("not selected database");

 $chois_1 = array();
 $chois_2 = array();
 $chois_3 = array();
 $chois_4 = array();
 $Question = array();
 $correct = array();
 $correct['Correct_Answer']= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Correct_Answer']) ;
 $Question['Question']= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Question']) ;
 $chois_1['Choise_1']= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Choise_1']) ;
 $chois_2['Choise_2']= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Choise_2']) ;
 $chois_3['Choise_3'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Choise_3']) ;
 $chois_4['Choise_4'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Choise_4']) ;
 if (isset($_POST['E_No'])) {
     $E_no = $_POST['E_No'];
}
     if (isset($_REQUEST['courseID'])) {
    $courseId = $_REQUEST['courseID'];
     }

     $sql ="INSERT INTO question_bank (C_ID ,E_No , Question  , Choise_1  , Choise_2          ,         Choise_3 , Choise_4 , Correct_Answer
     , Question_Type )
          VALUES
          ('$courseId','$E_no',                            {$Question['Question']}','{$chois_1['Choise_1']}','{$chois_2['Choise_2']}','{$chois_3['Choise_3']}',
     '{$chois_4['Choise_4']}','{$correct['Correct_Answer']}','$_POST[Question_Type]')
     ";
          if (!mysql_query($sql,$connectdb))
            {
                    die ('Error :'.mysql_error());
            }
          echo "The Qustion is saved";
          echo '  <br />
          <a href="question.htm" >Add Another Question</a> <br />
          <a href="ManageStudents.htm">Manage Students</a> <br />
          <a href="Instructor.htm">Home</a>
          ';
          mysql_close($connectdb);
           ?>
```

Comment: An advice: as you've probably noticed, the error message states (among other things) line number. This is a very helpful information and also a hint on how to write queries: the more lines the easier to locate an error. More, in a reasonable way of course.

Comment: Can you tell us the structure of your table? Probably C_ID and E_NO are integers and you are trying to insert string into those fields.

Answer (score 2):

There is a ' missing in front of `{$Question['Question']}'`

Comment: @SaraS'h Just before `$sql ="INSERT...`, could you `var_dump($E_no);` and `var_dump($courseId);`? Both variables are set conditionally. It may happen that they are not set at all. `var_dump` will echo values of both variables.